# Auto translate any page with selenium python firefox

Tags: python, selenium

I need to translate some page before scraping, I already have this code for Chrome:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

option = Options()
prefs = {
    "translate_whitelists": {
        "es": "en",
        "ru": "en",
        "id": "en",
        "pt": "en",
        "ko": "en",
        "fr": "en",
        "ar": "en",
        "it": "en",
        "nl": "en",
        "th": "en",
        "tr": "en",
        "vi": "en",
        "he": "en",
        "ja": "en",
        "pl": "en"
    },
    "translate": {"enabled": "true"},
}
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
option.add_argument("--lang=en")
option.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=f"{getcwd()}\chromedriver.exe", options=option)
```

I looked for something similar for firefox but I couldn't find it and I can't use chrome anymore, because when I pass the parameter: `option.add_argument("--headless")` on some sites, chrome doesn't find the elements on the page

Comment: option.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080") Did you remember to set the window size for headless.

Comment: I spent the whole day trying to solve this, I was putting it to start maximized, but with your tip it's working now, thanks!

Comment: No problem have a nice day.